# Service Not Registered on Microsoft Authentication Library (Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, azure-ad-msal

I'm using a modified version of the example app from the MSAL Android library and for the past few weeks it worked like a charm but just yesterday it started crashing on me giving me this error:

> 2019-06-04 15:22:07.807 20645-20645/com.example.myApp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>
> EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.myApp, PID: 20645
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.myApp/com.example.myApp.Activities.LoginActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1001, result=2003, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.myApp/com.example.myApp.Activities.LoginActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.ui.browser.CustomTabsManager$1@f965d28
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3961)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3993)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1934)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6940)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1001, result=2003, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.myApp/com.example.myApp.Activities.LoginActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.ui.browser.CustomTabsManager$1@f965d28

I haven't changed anything with the logic of how the example app works. The only thing I did was move the logic of logging in into a separate static class.

The code still works with most phones and even on emulators but I can't get it to work anymore with my Oneplus 6. Has anyone encountered this before?

It's just weird because I haven't changed anything and it started to stop working all of a sudden.

This line of code causes the crash:

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    app?.handleInteractiveRequestRedirect(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for those who might be having the same problem as mine. I was originally using the default method for handling the authentication process (Via Intents and the BrowserTab).

Another method to authenticate would be to edit the `auth_config.json` file in the `Raw` folder and change the user agent to this `"authorization_user_agent": "WEBVIEW"`. You'll have to work with a WebView instead of the browser but it does prevent the app from crashing. You also won't need the intent filters in the `AndroidManifest` file if you're gonna go this route.

PS: I'm still unable to pinpoint what caused my phone specifically to crash though. I was able to test my app on a Galaxy S9 and also on emulators and they all work. My personal phone used to work until recently and is what prompted me to post here. If I find the cause I'll update this answer.